# SQL JSON_VALUE and JSON_QUERY Alternative in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core

I am trying to filter my sql table data based on a column which have json object using c# lambda.
Below is my sql query which i'm trying to convert in lambda expression

```
select * from SampleTable where JSON_VALUE(Data, '$.fld_test_column') like N'%sample_data%'
```

Expression which i have created for this query looks like this which isn't working

```
_context.SampleTable.Where(a => JObject.Parse(a.Data)["fld_test_column"].Contains("sample_data")).ToList();
```

Note: Here json obejct is having dynamic columns and structure so a model can not be created for this

Comment: EF Core knows nothing about `JObject` so query will be not translatable. [Check this link](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/52017204/expression-tree-to-sql-with-ef-core)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to specific problem and proving the link. DbFunction is used to map user defined sql function with efcore but in this scenarioi'm using JSON_Value which is system defined function. Found this link which helped to add this function with ef. [link](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/add-custom-database-functions-for-entity-framework-core#adding-more-database-functions)

Comment: This is planned for EF Core 7.0 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#json-columns